# User selected CSS stylesheet in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, themes

I'm working on a site in Rails and I'd like for the user to be able to change the CSS stylesheet to either a light or dark theme.

I have this in my view so that I can use a variable for the stylesheet:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag @current_stylesheet %>
```

I tried to change that variable by having a link in my view something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Light Theme', :action => "set_light", :id => @projects %>
```

that calls this function in my Controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def set_light
    @current_stylesheet = 'light'
  end
end
```

Is there a way to make something like this work?  Right now it says that the projects/set_light template is missing, but I don't want to make new templates, I'd just like to call set_light to change the stylesheet and refresh the current page.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this, or maybe a better way to approach it?

Answer (score 1):

to avoid having rails look for a 'set_light' template you can add a render call to the end of your action for a template you already have. for instance, just add

```
render :action => 'style_chooser'
```

or

```
render :template => 'style_chooser'
```

where style_chooser is the view you are presenting the user with or changing the style for